# Do I need to put a resistor at the collector of this MOSFET driver?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver

When I look at this schematic, I think of two scenarios but I don't know which one is correct:

1. Collector resistor does not exist. So, Both the transistor and the Mosfet provide a short circuit. A very high Current flows from the positive terminal of the battery to the collector and then comes out of the emitter and enters the gate of the Mosfet and exits from the source. Therefore, a resistor MUST connected between the positive terminal of the battery and collector to limit that high current.
2. Collector current is limited by the forward current of the diode which is limited by the resistor (R1). So, There's no need to use a resistor at the collector.

Which one of these scenarios is correct?

Thank you very much,

[image]

Comment: Just to clear up some confusion, maybe on my part, you realise that there is (virtually) no current flow between the gate and source terminals of a MOSFET? Your description sounds like you think it's a BJT.

Comment: Option 1 is certainly not correct. You seem to think both the (photo-)transistor and the MOSFET work the same way, but they don't. "and enters the gate of the Mosfet and exits from the source" It does not exits through the source of the MOSFET. The gate of the MOSFET is basically a capacitor that needs to be charged to switch the MOSFET ON. The current won't flow from gate to source. It comes out of the emitter of the transistor and goes to GND through R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A very high Current flows from the positive terminal of the battery to
>   the collector and then comes out of the emitter and enters the gate of
>   the Mosfet and exits from the source.

A MOSFET's gate-source impedance is tens of Mohm because it is a voltage driven device. However, it may have a sizable GS capacitance up to 10 nF so, theoretically there will be a short impulse of current that flows when the BJT turns on. However, that current is limited to a few tens of milli amps usually.

The current through the LED is limited (to about 10 or 20 mA) and the CTR (current transfer ratio of the opto) is somewhat limited to between 20% and 600% usually. This means that the BJT collector current might be between 2 mA and 120 mA.

There is no need to use a collector resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenarios are both wrong.

The gate of the mosfet is insulated. There's no way for gate current inside the mosfet. => In principle this circuit is ok. But your power supply voltage must not exceed the maximum allowed gate voltage that can be as low as 15 volts. Also the output transistor of your opto-coupler must stand the power supply voltage. If the PSU voltage is higher, say 50 volts, you must insert a voltage divider to protect the OC and mosfet input.

BTW. the computer side of the circuit is unusual. Generally the outputs work better when the load is against the + voltage ie. pulled down by the output.

Comment: Ironically, so is your 'senario' - it's 'scenario' :-)

Comment: @TonyM I wilk crect it ass soon as i get a prpecr ke byoa rd